# Regular language. Proof

Tags: regular-language

Let $L$ be regular language over $\{0,1\}$. Prove that $L'$ is also regular:
$$L' = \{ w | w \in L \mbox{ and  among words of length |w|, w is the least in lexicographic order.} \}$$
To explain, for example, if $ L = \{ 10001, 00001, 001,000\}$ then $L'= \{00001, 000\}$
Please hint me.

Comment: An infinite union of regular languages has no reason to be regular. Otherwise, every language would be regular.

Comment: As noted by @J.-E.Pin your proof is incorrect, the proof I know is very complicated it involves an automaton with an an exponential number of states , I don't know if there is a simpler proof

Comment: Ok, you are right. Union of FINITE regular language is still regular.
I edited post to make more clear. 
@Elaqqad, Do you consider use a Myhill-Nerode's theorem?
Anyway, can you refer me to this proof?

And, If someone knows a simple proof, please share. :)

Comment: @user180834 I added my proof to your question so you can read it

Answer (score 2):

Given $M=(\{0,1\}^*,Q,q_0,'\cdot',\{q_f\})$ a finite state automaton recognizing $L$, The idea of the proof is the following, given a word in $L'$ we run in parallel $M$ over all smaller  words then $w$ and if one of them reach the final state then the word is rejected otherwise we accept if it's accepted.

so let's take $M'=\left\{\{0,1\right\}^*,Q',q_0', Q_f\}$:

- $Q'=Q\times 2^{Q}$
- $q'_0=q_0\times \emptyset$
- $Q_f=\left\{q_f\times S\big/ q_f\not \in S\right\}$

and the transition function is defined as follow:
$$\begin{align}\forall (q,S)\in Q'& : t((q,S),0)=(q.0,S.0)\\
  \forall (q,S)\in Q'& : t((q,S),1)=(q.1,S.1\cup \{q.0\})\end{align}$$
where $S.a=\{q.a\big/a\in S\}$

Given a word $w$ such that $M'(w)=(q,S)$,it's easy to see that $S$ contains exactly the set of states reached by $M$ over smaller words then the word $w$ and if this set contains $q_f$ this means that there exists a smaller word $w'$ such that $w'$ in $L$ and |w'|=|w| and this means that the automaton $M'$ must reject $w$ in this case, if $S$ deos not contain $q_f$ then the word $w$ is accepted iff $q=q_f$.